# Python code to c# .net for HTTP Post to API

Tags: c#, python, .net, post

I need help converting the follow Python code to c# .net.  This code is posting/uploading a text file to a webserver.  The Python script has been tested and works.  I have tried a few solutions with HTTPClient and WebRequest with no luck.  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
# request a session
client = requests.session()

# Establish the URL
newurl = 'https://localhost/filedist/upload/'
source_file = 'data/test.txt'

headers = {'Authorization': 'Token MYTOKEN'}

# Populate the values with our environment and target path
values = dict(environment='dev', path='Business/Tools')

files = dict(file=open(source_file, 'rb'))
r = client.post(newurl, files=files, data=values, headers=headers)
```

Here is my latest attempt, which currently is getting a 'Forbidden' error.

```
    public static async Task<string> UploadFile(string path, string fileName)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string NewURL = "https://localhost/filedist/upload/";
        string SourceFile = path;
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token MYTOKEN");
        Stream fs = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        content.Add(CreateFileContent(fs, fileName, "text/plain"));
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "environment", "dev" }, { "path", "Business/Tools" } };
        content.Add(new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));

        var response = await client.PostAsync(NewURL, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return "true";
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }

    }
    private static StreamContent CreateFileContent(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "UploadedFile",
                FileName = "\"" + fileName + "\""
            };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
            return fileContent;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason the python is reading binary and the c# text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% on this, but I don't think you can set the authorization header that way.  Try using the client authorization header type.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", "MYTOKEN");
```

Comment: Thanks, but the api expects it.  It is literally...
Token xxxxxxxx

Comment: I understand that it expects it, but the httpclient won't let you set an authorization header by using the defaultrequestheaders.add method.  You need to set it wiht the Authorization property of the DefaultRequestHeaders.

Comment: I wish I could buy you lunch.  It works!  Thank you.

I also needed to change my parameters to use
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("environment", "dev");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("path", "Business/Tools");